# Greater than and lesser than in if statements in Javascript

Tags: javascript, validation, if-statement, return

I need help. Using the greater and lesser than validation message does not work.
I have 3 times 3 conditions for certain drugs, which I want to validate. Three times 'more, three times 'lido' and three times 'kane'.

Whenever I run the whole code the validation messages are not being replaced. So the first   validation message for 'More' remains, but only the 'too high and too low messages, followed by the Lido and then the Kane error messages.
I tried to replace these with the 'Test' message when using greater than and lesser than, but to no avail. Can someone help?  I am trying to replace the false validation message with the true one, or at least continue with the next false validation message, but I don't want to display them all.

```
   if (more > 0.4) {
    error.innerHTML = "More is too high<br>Press 'Clear All' and start again"
     moreDose.value = "" 
     return false;
    
   } 
    if (more < 0.2) {
      error.innerHTML = "More is too low<br>Press 'Clear All' and start again"
      moreDose.value = ""  
      return false;     
  }

  if (more > 0.2 && more < 0.4) {
    error.innerHTML = "Test"
    return true;
  }

  if (lido > 3) {
    error2.innerHTML = "Lido is too high<br>Press 'Clear All' and start again"
    lidoDose.value = ""  
    return false;     
    }

    if (lido < 0.6) {
      error2.innerHTML = "Lido is too low<br>Press 'Clear All' and start again"
      lidoDose.value = ""
      return false;
            }
    if (lido < 0.6 && lido > 3) {
    error2.innerHTML = "Test 2"
    return true;
    }


    if (kane > 1.2) {
    error3.innerHTML = "Kane is too high<br>Press 'Clear All' and start again"
    ketaDose.value = ""  
    return false; 
    }
    if (kane < 0.12) {
      error3.innerHTML = "Kane is too low<br>Press 'Clear All' and start again"
      ketaDose.value = ""
      return false;
  }
  if (kane < 0.12 && kane> 1.2) {
    error3.innerHTML = "Test 3"
    return true;
   }
```

Comment: To start with, all of your `&&` conditions are logically impossible. Did you get the signs backwards maybe?

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, but even when corrected as I just did I have the same problem.

Comment: What are the required conditions to have a valid result? We can start from there.

Comment: These below are the correct outcomes  
if (more > 0.2 && more < 0.4) {
    error.innerHTML = "Test"
    return true;
  } and  

if (lido > 0.6 && lido < 3) {
    error2.innerHTML = "Test 2"
    return true;
    } and

  if (kane > 0.12 && kane < 1.2) {
    error3.innerHTML = "Test 3"
    return true;
   }
but I need to check the other conditions first. The problem is that the error messages are printed out even when the correct input is given.

Comment: You don't handle the cases where `more` is exactly `0.2` or `0.4`. You only check for greater than and less than, but not `==`.

Comment: Also, you'll never get to the test for `lido` and `kane`, since all the tests of `more` return from the function.

Comment: so I have now added >= 0.2 and <=0.4  and only get past the first validation message of 'more', because return is set to true. The function does not continue to check. How is it possible to check three statements with if statements? Is it at all possible?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't return in each `if` block, because when any of the early tests succeeds, it will never perform the laster tests.

Insetear, use `if/else if/else` to check mutually exclusive conditions. This will also solve the problem that you were omitting the cases where an input is exactly equal to one of the range boundaries.

```js
var moreDose = document.getElementById("more");
var lidoDose = document.getElementById("lido");
var ketaDose = document.getElementById("kane");

var error = document.getElementById("error");
var error2 = document.getElementById("error2");
var error3 = document.getElementById("error3");

function validate(more, lido, kane) {
  if (more > 0.4) {
    error.innerHTML = "More is too high<br>Press 'Clear All' and start again"
    moreDose.value = ""
  } else if (more < 0.2) {
    error.innerHTML = "More is too low<br>Press 'Clear All' and start again"
    moreDose.value = ""
  } else {
    error.innerHTML = "Test"
  }

  if (lido > 3) {
    error2.innerHTML = "Lido is too high<br>Press 'Clear All' and start again"
    lidoDose.value = ""
  } else if (lido < 0.6) {
    error2.innerHTML = "Lido is too low<br>Press 'Clear All' and start again"
    lidoDose.value = ""
  } else {
    error2.innerHTML = "Test 2"
  }


  if (kane > 1.2) {
    error3.innerHTML = "Kane is too high<br>Press 'Clear All' and start again"
    ketaDose.value = ""
  } else if (kane < 0.12) {
    error3.innerHTML = "Kane is too low<br>Press 'Clear All' and start again"
    ketaDose.value = ""
  } else {
    error3.innerHTML = "Test 3"
  }
}

document.getElementById("validate").addEventListener("click", function() {
  validate(parseFloat(moreDose.value),
    parseFloat(lidoDose.value),
    parseFloat(ketaDose.value));
});
```

```html
More: <input id="more" type="number"><br> Lido: <input id="lido" type="number"><br> Kane: <input id="kane" type="number"><br>
<input id="validate" value="Validate">

<div id="error"></div>
<div id="error2"></div>
<div id="error3"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your generous help. I will need to play with your code tomorrow, as it is built into another function and I am running into some small issues.